# Performance issue with For loop in VSTO C# while getting emails from outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am having issues with looping through the emails in outlook inbox folders (C# VSTO add in Outlook).
I was using foreach loop but it consumes a lot of memory and then causes the exception: out of system/memory resources.
So, I am using for loop now which does not cause that error but for one of the folders it is really slow, reads less than 5-8 emails per second. This folder contains a bit more than 100,000 emails. For all other folders the speed is between 30-35 emails.

The code is:

```
Static void IterateMessages(Outlook.Folder folder){

        int tempCount = folder.Items.Count;
        if (folder.Items != null)
        {
            Object item;
            for (int k = 1; k <= tempCount; k++)
            {
                item = folder.Items[k];
                if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    emailCount++;
                    try
                    {
                        SaveAttachment(item);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("An error occurred Iterate Message: '{0}'", e);
                    }
                }
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(item);
                item = null;
            }
            tempCount = 0;
        }
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(folder);
    }
```

It would be great if someone can help with this issue. While using foreach loop the speed was approx. 40-45 emails per second. Also, this method is called from another for loop which iterates through the folders, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, looping through all items in a folder is not  good idea. Do you really need to do that?

You keep retrieving the Items collection in the loop (`folder.Items[k]`). Cache `Items` before entering the loop:

```
Items items = folder.Items;
for (int k = 1; k <= items.Count; k++)
{
  object item = items[k];
  ...
}
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
```

You are leaking references (they will later will released by the GC of course), but since you are using FinalReleaseComObject...

```
object item = items[k];
MailItem mailItem = item as MailItem;
if (mailItem != null)
{
  ...
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
}
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks for the reply, I want to loop through all items in a folder because I want to get the attachments from all the mails, I am open to trying a different way if there is any to perform the same action.

Comment: Also, I will implement your solution and see if it makes some difference

Comment: Thanks, It made it faster

Answer (score 1):

Properly releasing underlying COM objects is not enough for your goal. Instead of iterating over all items in the folder you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to find items with attachments and only then you can iterate over all items with attachments only. The query may use the SQL notation (VBA):

```
query ="@SQL=" & chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & chr(34) & "=1"
```

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.